# DNN Fail to install Authentication Provider sd file specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

I am trying to install a third party Authentication Provider. When I try to install the zipped folder using the install extension wizard it fails to locate the file even though its both in the zip and in the folder DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/Fellows/ on my site. I'm confused as I have been able to install other modules and it had no problem reading the files.

Part of the .dnn file code:

```
<components>
    <component type="AuthenticationSystem">
      <authenticationService>
        <type>FellowsAuthentication</type>
        <settingsControlSrc>DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/Fellows/Settings.ascx</settingsControlSrc>
        <loginControlSrc>DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/Fellows/Login.ascx</loginControlSrc>
        <logoffControlSrc />
      </authenticationService>
    </component>
    <component type="File">
      <files>
        <basePath>DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/Fellows</basePath>
        <file>
          <path>App_LocalResources</path>
          <name>Login.ascx.resx</name>
           </file>
```

I get the error message:

```
  Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - E:\DNN\Install\Temp\z2ypiwfl\App_LocalResources\Login.ascx.resx
```

It's weird that it seems to be trying to read them from a temp folder. Why is that?

Comment: Which authenticator, and do you have a download link so I can test?

Comment: https://ufile.io/fs7cq

Comment: It's a custom one that uses the CMS Personify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the zip file itself. While installing, dnn expects the files to be in a temp folder.

```
\Install\Temp\j1hnum0c\FellowsAuthentication.dnn
```

However in the zip there are folders zipped inside along with the files `\AuthenticationServices\Fellows`, so the unzipped path in the DNN temp folder becomes

```
\Install\Temp\j1hnum0c\AuthenticationServices\Fellows\FellowsAuthentication.dnn
```

Therefore the installer cannot find the `.dnn` file and install fails. Unzip the files and re-zip the contents of `Fellows` in the zip. Then it works, tested it.

The zip file only should contain.

```
FellowsAuthentication.dnn
Login.ascx
Login.ascx.cs
Settings.ascx
Settings.ascx.cs

App_LocalResources
    Login.ascx.resx
    Settings.ascx.resx
```

Comment: I zipped up the fellows and tried to install it. I still got these errors. Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - E:\DNN\Install\Temp\hr2ss3gu\App_LocalResources\Login.ascx.resx
Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - E:\DNN\Install\Temp\hr2ss3gu\App_LocalResources\Settings.ascx.resx
Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - E:\DNN\Install\Temp\hr2ss3gu\Login.ascx
Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: -

Comment: Updated my answer. It looks like you forgot to zip the `App_LocalResources` folder

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I fixed it. Thanks so much!